# colors.xml - Error: XML document structures must start and end in the same entity

Tags: android

How can I solve this error?

> C:\Users\spark\AndroidStudioProject\MyApplication\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml:4:101: Error: XML document structures must start and end in the same entity

```
<component name="libraryTable">
    <library name="Gradle: com.android.support:customview-28.0.0">
        <CLASSES>
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/customview-28.0.0.aar
```

[image]

Comment: Add and put words not images...

Comment: the problem is: C:\Users\spark\AndroidStudioProject\MyApplication\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml:4:101: Error: XML document structures must start and end in the same entity

Comment: Went ahead and edited this VLQ question since triage disposed as 'needs editing'..... https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/21371700

Comment: Copy and paste the description in your question, I can not type things from your image, copy and paste the data in your image so that I can edit it and you can just copy and paste it back, Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

So, the error that you put in the comments is for the `colors.xml` file. And that file shouldn't contain `<component>` tags, or refer to Gradle stuff.

For example, should look like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

I don't think Android Studio is the problem here, but if you think it is, I suggest you use a different version of Android Studio.

Comment: The problem is the bug in the Android Studio. Tried deleting the android folder in user/Username and uninstalling/re-installing Android to solve the problem but nothing seems to work.. It generates some gradle-related incomplete code in colors.xml which even after replacing with correct code doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
[image]

Comment: Great answer. But its an old issue.

Comment: Great answer. But its an old issue.